# Running Go in Geany

Tags: ide, go, executable, geany

I am trying to run go code in geany.

Unfortunately I get this error when I try to execute:

```
./geany_run_script.sh: 5: ./geany_run_script.sh: go: not found
```

I know some posts say that one must compile or build before running but the `go run` command compiles and runs at the same time, so ...

How does one run go code in geany?

Comment: Is `go` located in `/usr/bin`?

Comment: I would agree with Kyle Kanos, it seems go is not visible (not in your $PATH, nor an custom Geany path). Is the go executable in a standard folder like /usr/bin or in some custom folder ? If so, is that folder on the $PATH ? From your message, it seems that geany tries to run the command `go` without any path information, and fails to find it.

Comment: My go executable is located in /usr/local/go/bin. And it is listed in my $PATH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to go to Build>Set Build Commands in the Geany options, under the Execute commands section, write the full path to your go executable, so `/path/to/go/bin/go run "%f"`.